# npm install stuck on "normalizeTree: http request GET https://registry.npmjs.o"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

so for few hours, I'm trying to install angular cli - but the npm package is just not working.
i've disabled Firewall, and even saw some posts about changing the path variable - nothing works.

any ideas?

the log is as follows, while i tried to run **"npm -verbose install -g @angular/cli --loglevel=silly"**

```
npm sill install loadCurrentTree
npm sill install readGlobalPackageData
npm sill fetchPackageMetaData @angular/cli
npm sill fetchNamedPackageData @angular/cli
npm sill mapToRegistry name @angular/cli
npm sill mapToRegistry scope (from package name) @angular
npm verb mapToRegistry no registry URL found in name for scope @angular
npm sill mapToRegistry using default registry
npm sill mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm sill mapToRegistry data Result {
npm sill mapToRegistry   raw: '@angular/cli',
npm sill mapToRegistry   scope: '@angular',
npm sill mapToRegistry   escapedName: '@angular%2fcli',
npm sill mapToRegistry   name: '@angular/cli',
npm sill mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
npm sill mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
npm sill mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
npm sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 6:52:04 AM
npm verb request id 8d89f8490dc17414
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli
[..................] - normalizeTree: http request GET https://registry.npmjs.o
```

Comment: What are your Node.JS and NPM versions ? 
Also, do you have a proxy ?
Can you do a simple NPM install on a project succesfully ?

Comment: Thanks! it was indeed a proxy (Triton thingy), add it as a comment and i'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably a proxy issue !

Don't forget to configure NPM (and any other package manager such as Yarn) with the following commands :

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Source : https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/